# Can we burn the tag meta-information?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I think [meta-information](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-information) is a duplicate of [metadata](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata).

I already moved questions.
Should we burn it, or add it as synonym to metadata?

Comment: I think burninate.

Comment: Thanks for completing this.